# Probability and proportion from standard deviation and mean

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I do not know how to start this problem-help needed-kindly help me

> 1. The lifetimes of a colour TV picture tube is normally distributed, with a mean of 8 yrs and a standard deviation of 2 years.
>
> (i)    What is the probability that a picture tube will last more than 10 yrs?
>
> (ii)    If the firm guarantees the picture tube for 4 yrs, what percentage of the tubes sold will have to be replaced?

Comment: I have edited the title of this post, however in the future please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for i, you need the lifetime to be more than one standard deviation high.  for ii, it needs to be more than 2 standard deviations low.

Comment: thanks for the hint but how should i start this problem

Comment: Do you know about the z score table?  This is an exercise in reading it.